# SQL exact match in query for Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, match, google-query-language

Sure there is a simple way to solve this i'm just to rusty to remember it.

Heres my formula:

```
=QUERY('Test Sheet'!$3:$728, "select K where C contains '"SD"'")
```

Now in my test sheet there K has value "SD" and also "ASD" i want it to get the "SD" one only and not the ASD as well.

What do i put around the SD to specify that?

Thank you

Comment: Just `=QUERY('Test Sheet'!$3:$728, "select K where C ='SD'")` maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=QUERY('Test Sheet'!3:728, "select K where C = 'SD'")
```